# What use are Fermat’s Little Theorem and Wilson’s theorems in number theory?

Tags: number-theory

Do these theorems have any real life applications? We cannot use them to find primes as both are pretty inefficient for large numbers.

Comment: What is this "real life" you speak of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fermat’s Little Theorem plays a key role in modern life in the proof of correctness of the [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) algorithm for public-key cryptography.